# What directories of file system should I store git repositories, according to best-practice?

Tags: git

Reading about git I find references to "where you keep all your local git repositories", but I can't seem to find explicit recommendations on this topic.

Currently I keep my git repos wherever I work on them; *e.g.*, `~/Work/Publications/topicA/foo/` or `~/Education/UofA/PhDThesis/`, etc.

Should I instead keep all git repos in one directory and symlink to them?  I might be mistaken in thinking that people do this, so let me know in the comments if you think so.

*N.b.*, if you are going to comment/answer with "you can do whatever you like with your local git repos", you should be prepared to show that there is no advantage one way or another.  Otherwise you are just pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Some Ideas.

- can also use environment variable 'GIT_DIR' to to set location of repository or set an alias to git_misc=git --git-dir=MY_MISC_FILE_DIR.GIT
- set Local repos's to file server so IT will back them up nightly.
- set local repos's to  C:\gits\MYPROJ.git.  Then you can view/backup all of them from a single command and location.
- set repos's containining only lab data dumps to C:\gits\labdata.  Avoids having to name them data_try1, data_try2, data_try3.
- make a repository for just your task specific temporary development files that are too specific for general consumption